# Display a list of items without using a list

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, math, while-loop

I am trying to create a program that inputs the price and tax rate and returns the item number, price, tax rate, and item price in an orderly format.
Here is the criteria:

- The user can enter multiple items until the user says otherwise.
- It calculates and display the total amount of purchased items on the bottom.
- The price gets a 3% discount if the total amount is 1000 or more

**I am not allowed to use arrays to solve this problem** and I must separate the inputs from the outputs on the screen.

An example output is shown here:

```
Enter the price: 245.78
Enter the tax rate: 12
Are there any more items? (y/n) y
Enter the price: 34
Enter the tax rate: 10
Are there any more items? (y/n) y
Enter the price: 105.45
Enter the tax rate: 7
Are there any more items? (y/n) n


Item  Price  Tax Rate %  Item Price
====================================
1     245.78        12%      275.27
2     34.00         10%      37.40
3     105.45        7%       112.83

Total amount: $425.51
```

Here is my code so far:

```
price= float(input('Enter the price: '))
taxRate= float(input('Enter the tax rate: '))
itemPrice = price * (1 + taxRate/100)
acc= 0
while True:
  query=input('Are there any more items? (y/n)')
  if query== 'y':
    price= float(input('Enter the price: '))
    taxRate= float(input('Enter the tax rate: '))
    itemPrice = price * (1 + taxRate/100)
    print(itemPrice )
    acc+=1
  elif query=='n':
    break
print ("Item     Price    Tax Rate%    Item Price")
print ("=========================================")
print( (acc+1) , format(price,'10.2f'), format(taxRate,'10.2f') ,
      format(itemPrice,'14.2f') )

for num in range(0,acc):
  print (acc, price, taxRate, itemPrice)
```

The output is shown as this:

```
Enter the price: 245.78
Enter the tax rate: 12
Are there any more items? (y/n)y
Enter the price: 34
Enter the tax rate: 10
37.400000000000006
Are there any more items? (y/n)y
Enter the price: 105.45
Enter the tax rate: 7
112.8315
Are there any more items? (y/n)n
Item     Price    Tax Rate%    Item Price
=========================================
3     105.45       7.00         112.83
2 105.45 7.0 112.8315
2 105.45 7.0 112.8315
```

I just have a hard time trying to do this without using an array.. can anyone be of assistance?

Comment: Are `dict`s allowed?

Comment: This doesn't seem possible without a sort of data structure

Comment: dicts arent allowed as wel

Comment: Is the tax rate always an integer? No decimals to display? You do this in your code, but in the example at the top, there are no decimals displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a string as a buffer for the output?

Like this:

```
out = ""
acc = 0
totalAmount = 0
query = 'y'
while query == 'y':
    price = float(input('Enter the price: '))
    taxRate = float(input('Enter the tax rate: '))
    itemPrice = price * (1 + taxRate/100)
    acc += 1
    totalAmount += itemPrice
    out += f"{acc:>4} {price:9.2f} {taxRate:11.2f}% {itemPrice:13.2f}\n"
    query = input('Are there any more items? (y/n) ')

print("Item     Price    Tax Rate%    Item Price")
print("=========================================")
print(out)
print(f"Total amount: ${totalAmount:.2f}")

if totalAmount >= 1000:
    print("    Discount: 3%")
    print(f"Total amount: ${totalAmount*0.97:.2f} (after discount)")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!